# How to add up unique values from table in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in SQL that looks like this

```
Person  brand   brand_spend category    category_spend
0   p1  b1       20           c1           100
1   p1  b2       50           c1           100
2   p2  b1       25           c2           40
3   p1  b3       30           c1           100
4   p1  b2       15           c2           70
```

I need to tag every customer based on percentage spend he has made  at a brand based on total category spend where that brand is present.
So essentially I would want to tag Person `p1` for brand `b1' as percentage spend at 'b1` which should be calculated as  45/ 140

How this can be achieved. If I roll up on brand level to find total category spend then I think duplicates rows would add up.

I just want to find customer's Spend at a brand based on total spend at Brand for all categories where that brand is present.

Comment: And the result for `p1` on `b3` should then be `30/100`?

Comment: @cars10m yes this is correct

Comment: But, wait: `p1` only spent a total of `20` on brand `b1`. The other spending amount (`25`)  was spent by `p2`. So shouldn't the correct result for `p1 on b1` be `20/140`?

Comment: @Andreas I have tried attempting it. You can find it in the added answer by me

Answer (score 0):

You need grouping on two levels, as shown here:

```
select person, brand, sum(brand_spend) personspend, spendbrandallcats, 
       round(sum(brand_spend)/spendbrandallcats,3) pbratio from tbl t 
inner join (  -- brand statistics: sum of all spends per brand in all categories
 select brand br, sum(casp) spendbrandallcats from tbl 
 inner join ( -- category statistics: total category sums
   select category ca, sum(brand_spend) casp from tbl group by category
 ) catspend ON ca=category
 group by brand
) brandstats on br=brand
group by person,brand
```

These are the results:

```
person brand personspend spendbrandallcats pbratio
p1     b1    20          140               0.143
p1     b2    65          140               0.464
p1     b3    30          100               0.3
p2     b1    25          140               0.179
```

See the little demo here: https://rextester.com/SVNH27609

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things are not as complicated as it seems and a simple query does the trick.

```
select person , brand , sum(prsn_brand_spend) ,
sum(category_spend)  , (sum(prsn_brand_spend)/sum(category_spend)) as perc_spend
from tbl group by person , brand
```

The Results are

```
person  brand   brand_spend category_spend  perc
    p1  b1       20            100           0.200000
    p1  b2       65            170          0.382353
    p1  b3       30            100          0.300000
    p2  b1       25            40          0.625000
```